# Shrinkwrap modifier is not applying properly

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap, retopology

I've been trying to retopologize a high poly mesh and everything is going pretty well with it. However there is one section of the mesh that snapping to the nearest face just doesn't work on and I can't figure out why. It works as intended on virtually every other part of the mesh, just not the lower abdomen. On this part of the mesh, it follows the contours of the mesh but offsets it a bit away from the surface. I tried to use the shrinkwrap modifier to get around this and it worked well in preview, but when I apply the modifier it behaves the same way as the snap function did. I don't know why this changed behavior between the preview and application of the modifier. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Image 1
Shrinkwrap preview, everything looks good. The low poly mesh (skin toneish color) and the high poly mesh (default grey) are overlapping)

Image 2
Mesh after applying the shrinkwrap. It goes back to how it looked before, when I used the snap to nearest face function to move the verts

Image 3
Visible gap between the two meshes. I'm not sure if this is significant for baking maps yet

[image: Shrinkwrap preview, everything looks good. The low poly mesh (skin toneish color) and the high poly mesh (default grey) are overlapping)]

[image: Mesh after applying the shrinkwrap. It goes back to how it looked before, when I used the snap to nearest face function to move the verts.]

[image: Visible gap between the two meshes. I'm not sure if this is significant for baking maps yet]

Comment: The likeliest reason for this is that you have modifiers out of order: maybe a displace followed by a shrinkwrap.  The displace gets overridden by the sw, until you apply the sw.  But really, we'd need a file to tell you why.  Low poly *should* be outside of high poly for purposes of baking anyways (although possibly only virtually, via ray extrusion) so there shouldn't be a problem for baking.

Comment: The only other modifier is the armature, I've tried moving it up and down but that had no effect on the shrinkwrap